# How to run a custom html file with budo (or browserify)?

Tags: javascript, html, browserify, livereload

[Budo](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo) does great job to browserify and run with livereload. But it is using `index.html` by default. That makes it less convenient with several html files. Is it possible to run it against a custom html file?

It mentions to accept all browserify options but I couldn't find the relevant one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dir` flag to point to a custom path where you house a different index.html file:

eg: `budo index.js --dir myCustomBudoDir`

this will serve your index.html out of your `myCustomBudoDir` directory

Answer (score 0):

If your launch dir has an index.html, budo will use that. I've got a super simple project [here](https://github.com/peterbarraud/rapo-browserify-budo).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Budo has the name `index.html` baked in, so using [separate directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674851/how-to-run-a-custom-html-file-with-budo-or-browserify/46984101#46984101) is the way to go, see the `dir` option [in the doc](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo/blob/master/docs/api-usage.md#opts)